# Is there a industry interface standard for TTS and ASR?

Tags: voip, text-to-speech

I am asked to develop a text-to-speech module in our product, which should support a variety of text-to-speech engines.

Is there a standard describes how to interface with third party TTS(text-to-speech) service or ASR(auto-speak-recognition) service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most ASR's use [Media Resource Control Protocol (MRCP)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-speechsc-mrcpv2-27) as the standard for their interface.  It can also be used for TTS.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on what is your purpose or the field you would use ASR & TTS in.

you can use MRCP to control ASR, TTS media resources if you will use it in IVR (Interactive Voice Response) apps like call centers and so on, in this case you would interface your MRCP server with Voice Gateway like CISCO and VXML server.
a famous and common MRCP implementation is [unimrcp](http://www.unimrcp.org/) , its a C implementation of the protocol , its a good and stable open source project.

but at end, it depends on your purpose as I said, you may never need to use MRCP, you can use your TTS engine as a stand alone server if it would work alone.

famous open source TTS engines are [Mary TTS](http://mary.dfki.de/) written in Java, [Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/) written in C++.

famous open source ASR engines are [cmu Sphinx4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/) written in Java, [Julius](http://julius.sourceforge.jp/en_index.php/) written in C.